# Why SecurityExpressionRoot is always setting DenyAllPermissionEvaluator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm migrating my applications to spring v6 & spring-boot:3.0.16.

I have a custom PermissionEvaluator where I have override the `hasPermission()` method.

```
public final class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        // your implementation
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

I'm using `@PreAuthorize` to validate permission like -

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#vehicle, 'Optimised')")
    @GetMapping("/authorize")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authorize(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,
                                        @RequestHeader(value="Vehicle", required=true) String vehicle){

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Vehicle Validated Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I'm using latest `@EnableMethodSecurity` in Security config, which looks like -

```
package com.test.am.authorizer.security;

import com.test.springsecurity.*;
import com.test.controller.RestAccessDeniedHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.Advisor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Role;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor;
import org.springframework.security.authorization.method.PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String anonymousKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder());
        jwtAuthProvider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomTokenConverter());
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManager(anonymousKey);

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new TokenAuthenticationEntryPoint());



        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(request -> authenticationManager))
                .anonymous(anonymous ->
                        // TODO do not allow anonymous access
                        anonymous.key(anonymousKey))

                
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());

        return http.build();
    }

    
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(String anonymousKey) {
        JwtAuthenticationProvider provider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder());
        provider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(new MyTokenConverter());
        List<GrantedAuthority> anonymousAuthorities = AuthorityUtils
                .createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS");
        return authentication -> {
            try {
                return provider.authenticate(authentication);
            } catch (InvalidBearerTokenException e) {
                log.error("InvalidBearerTokenException: Error in authentication");
                throw new AccessDeniedException("InvalidBearerTokenException: Error in authentication");
            }
        };
    }

    private NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        String awsRegion = System.getenv("my_region");
        NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = createDecoder(region);
        decoder.setJwtValidator(
                MyJwtValidators.createDefaultclaimsValidation(
                        "custom:claim_name"));
        return decoder;
    }



    @Bean(name = "permissionEvaluator")
    @Order(1)
    public PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator() {
        return new CustomPermissionEvaluator();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    


}
```

Now problem is every time when I call the method `authorize` with valid access token, my `customPermissonEvaluator` never invoke, Even the JWT authentication is succesfully done and decision is granted but `DenyAllPermissionEvaluator` returns `Access Denied`.

Seems like My `CustomePErmissionEvaluator` never invokes with `hasPermission()`.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: I ran into excact same issue. For some reason the PermissionEvaluator is not applied in the PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're attempting to set up a permission evaluator for a legacy method using the GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration. However, in your code, you've employed the `@EnableMethodSecurity` annotation. To address this, I recommend referring to the migration document that explains how to utilize the `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. This will help clarify the situation. You can find detailed guidance here: [MethodSecurityExpressionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#servlet-replace-permissionevaluator-bean-with-methodsecurityexpression-handler)